# Authenticate in Dovecot with plus "+" sign in address

Tags: email, smtp, dovecot

We have dovecot 1.0.15, and when I try to authenticate with email "a+b", I fail to do it. But with email "a_b" it's OK.
We didn't configure any "plus addressing" in dovecot. Could anyone please give me advice how to fix this problem with authentication in dovecot with emails that have "+" in address?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `+` to `auth_username_chars` in your `dovecot.conf`

```
auth_username_chars = abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234567890.-_@+
```

Ref: [Dovecot Mailinglist](http://www.mail-archive.com/dovecot@dovecot.org/msg09489.html)

Comment: Excellent! I searched this configuration so long... :)